# Why equation 22 is subtracting the current rather than adding?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, current-source, discharge

[image]

Both the currents are going into resistors and should add to the voltage across resistors, hence the voltage across capacitor ?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTAXA5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is how your circuit looks like.

Look at \$i_c\$. I assumed it in that direction. If \$V_c\$ is the upper node of the capacitor, then it means \$i_c = C\frac{dV_c}{dt}\$.

If you assumed \$i_c\$ to be in the opposite direction, then take \$i_c = -C\frac{dV_c}{dt}\$

Either way, you will end up in same answer.

In the solution, They have assumed the current directions like in the circuit I have drawn, so \$i_c = C\frac{dV_c}{dt}\$

Therefore \$i = 1.5i - i_c \$

Therefore \$v_c = (R1+R2).(1.5i - i_c) = (R1+R2).(1.5i - C\frac{dV_c}{dt})\$

Answer (score 0):

No, the first term represents the current in the middle leg, and the second term represents how much of that is flowing through the capacitor. What's left over (the difference) is what determines the voltage across the resistors.

Answer (score 0):

\$i_1\$ is the current through the resistors and is equal to the dependent source current minus the capacitor current \$i_c\$ under KCL.

It is defined with a sign that makes the capacitor charge with the polarity shown when it is positive. It's arbitrary, you could flip the +/- on the capacitor and define \$i_c\$ the other way, in which case, of course, it would work out to be a number of the opposite sign.

In any case you know that 1.5\$i_1\$ - \$v_c\$/30 - \$i_c\$ (or +\$i_c\$ depending on definition) = 0, since the sum of all currents at a node must be zero.

Comment: its given that that vc=2v with the shown polarity, so the current through c should be same direction as dependent sourc and should enter the upper node. giving the equation    1.5i1 - vc/30 + ic

Comment: @PankajKumar, knowing the instantaneous voltage across a capacitor doesn't tell you which direction current is flowing through the capacitor. You need to know \$\frac{{\rm d}v_c}{{\rm d}t}\$ to know which way the capacitor current is flowing.

Comment: Or if you mean that capacitor current should be considered positive when it goes in to the upper node, that's also incorrect. Under passive sign convention, a branch current is positive when it goes in to the + side of the branch.